# Zookeeper management interface in monitoring center displays abnormal

Tags: apache-dolphinscheduler

Describe

Zookeeper management interface in monitoring center displays abnormal。In fact, zookeepeer is running normally, both master and worker are successfully registered in zookeeper

Reproduce

1、After normal installation and deployment, log in to the dolphinscheduler web interface
2、Check the zookeeper management interface of the monitoring center, you can find this problem

Expected behavior

It can display various monitoring indicators of zookeeper normally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also meeted this problem, as shown in the picture, all items are -1

[zookeeper monitor data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZTIL.png)

this is zookeeper FourLetterWord problem, you can try command as follow

`echo ruok|nc localhost 2181`

if response no words, you should modify zoo.cfg

ruok is not executed because it is not in the whitelist.

you can add the following config in zoo.cfg

```
4lw.commands.whitelist=*
```

then restart zookeeper service.

the detail info please referer the ZK issue: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZOOKEEPER-2764